# While connecting to Redis in .net core getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, stackexchange.redis

This is error statement..

{"The assembly for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe + System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe could not be loaded; this usually means a missing assembly binding redirect - try checking this, and adding any that are missing; note that it is not always possible to add this redirects - for example 'azure functions v1'; it looks like you may need to use 'azure functions v2' for that - sorry, but that's out of our control"}

I am using .net core and C# while connecting to Redis can any one help me with this issue or let me know if some extra data is required.

My code

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = 
         ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);

IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
```

web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

NOTE: It is working fine on my local machine while deploying on UAT it not working fine

Edit:

1. When I depreciate the stackExchange.Redis 2.6.x-> 2.1.x/2.2.x
   and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 5.0.0-> 4.7.x
   Redis is getting connected but mySql won't.

2. I have installed redis on windows using .msi file. So, might be possible that lower version is getting installed.

Comment: What is your connection string?  See : https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: Are you running it locally or is this running on another machine?

Comment: @jdweng connection-string won't help an assembly load problem

Comment: the error message says what is happening; so: is there anything unusual in your setup? what version of .net core is this? you shouldn't need one, but have you tried adding a package-reference to System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe? (`<PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="6.0.0" />` in the csproj)

Comment: @MarcGravell : Title of posting says "While connecting to Redis in .net core getting error".  Could be the driver in connection string is causing error.

Comment: @jdweng the connection-string in SE.Redis doesn't choose a driver; there is no external driver - just SE.Redis

Comment: @MarcGravell : If OP is using TLS than another app is required which could give error.

Comment: @jdweng  <add name="RedisConnectionString" connectionString="localhost:6379"/>

Comment: @Marc Gravell .net version 4.7 is working fine in my local machine, but when I deploy it on my uat server in IIS, it's throwing error.

Comment: @jdweng TLS is handled directly in the lib, and either way: doesn't impact an assembly load error; note trying to be "that guy", but: I quite literally wrote this; it is not related to the connection string

Comment: @BikashPal Please try to register the relevant version of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe in the GAC of the system.
you need to use `gacutil` command to do it

Comment: @viveknuna the error cites .NET Core; .NET Core does not use the system GAC

Comment: @MarcGravell oh sorry my bad, I didn't notice .net core

Comment: @MarcGravell : I'm just saying the error is at runtime and not Load time.  I'm assuming that something in Redis is loading a executable at runtime.  I suspect it is what being used for TLS.

Comment: @MarcGravell : See if following will help.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @jdweng this is load-time; we *deliberately have things to try to force the assemblies to load at a known point*, to detect this problem and raise this specific message; the docs you've linked to refer to a tool that sits *on top of* the thing being discussed here.

Comment: @all  Is there anything to do with the process of Redis installation.. have installed using the .msi file. Do I have to install Linux a then install Redis